# Asp.Net4 Javascript/jquery Minification Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, refactoring, asp.net-mvc-4

I realize this might be stupid, and its probably caused by my lack of javascript/jquery knowledge (in terms of re-factoring etc..)

**I'm rendering a JQGrid component on my page like this.**

```
<script src="@System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/JQGrid")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var colNames = ['S ID', 'Shift Description'];
    var colModel = [
            { name: 'S_ID', index: 'S_ID', key: true, width: 55, editable: false, hidden: true, search: false },
            { name: 'Shift_Description', index: 'Shift_Description', width: 100, align: "right", editable: true, editrules: { required: true }, formoptions: { rowpos: 1, colpos: 1}}];

    RenderJQGrid("#theGrid", '#pager', '@ViewBag.Title', 600, colNames, colModel, 'S_ID', null, null, null, '@Url.Action("GridData")', '@Url.Action("Add")', '@Url.Action("Edit")', '@Url.Action("Delete")', '@Url.Action("ExportToExcel")');

</script>
```

**Inside my .js file, I only have this. (it's also the only file in the bundle)**

```
function RenderJQGrid(GridID, PagerID, Title, ModalWidth, ColNames, ColModel, InitSortCol, OnLoadComplete, EditBeforeShowOptions, AddBeforeShowOptions, URL_get, URL_add, URL_edit, URL_delete, URL_excel) {

   ... Logic
}
```

**I'm receiving this error in fiddler though.**

> /* Minification failed. Returning unminified contents.
>
> (1,10): run-time error CSS1031: Expected selector, found
>   'RenderJQGrid('
>
> (1,10): run-time error CSS1025: Expected comma or open brace, found
>   'RenderJQGrid('
>
> */

what am i doing wrong/missing? the code seemed fine when it was embedded inside my html page?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ran into a similar problem. My issue was that I was using a StyleBundle to bundle *.js files

Comment: no I had to change the code to use ScriptBundle instead. Works great now.